# Error in uploading django project on pythonanaywhere.com

Tags: django, web-development-server

I am uploading django project on pythonanywhere.com but it is showing
Error:-

```
2023-09-23 07:19:34,731: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:   File "/var/www/abhishekk_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 29, in <module>
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732: 
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:   File "/home/Abhishekk/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732: 
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:   File "/home/Abhishekk/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2023-09-23 07:19:34,732:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733: 
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733:   File "/home/Abhishekk/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733: 
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733:   File "/home/Abhishekk/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 193, in create
2023-09-23 07:19:34,733:     import_module(entry)
```

this error I have installed crispy_forms and written it in the installed_apps in setting.py and it is running perfectly on the localhost what is the problem?

I expected it to run perfectly and also I have Debug = False it

and I don't have any requirement.txt file.

Comment: Show your `requirements.txt` please. And please format you question for better reading.